# How do I pass the right option to select english?

Tags: package-options

OK I'm not a LaTeX developer but I'm using someone else's file to produce a document. I don't know LaTeX at all, How do I pass a command option to tell the package to use `english` and not `french` when this is in the `.cls` file?

```
\DeclareOption{french}{\ORG@isfrenchtrue}
\DeclareOption{english}{\ORG@isfrenchfalse}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Probably `\documentclass[english]{theclass}` (where `theclass` is the name of the class you're using.

Answer (score 4):

If the name of the document class you're using is `theclass`, then, judging from what you report,

```
\documentclass[english]{theclass}
```

is what you need.